# Can't get the text from LineEdit to pass to a function

Tags: godot, gdscript

Context:
I click on a button -> a `WindowDialogue` appears -> there are 2 `LineEdit` Nodes and a button

Supposed procedure:
I fill these `LineEdits`, press the button, and the function tied to the button receives the texts from the `LineEdits` (and creates a dictionary key-value pair).

Problem:
The texts from the `LineEdits` **do not** pass down to the function (through `connect()`).

I tried passing the text directly with `LineEdit.text`. I tried writing it in a different variable and passing the variable. The debug shows the function is getting executed (no problem with that), but the strings passed from the `LineEdits` are always **empty**. Somehow, it worked for some time when I explicitly pressed `ENTER` after filling the `LineEdits`. But after I tried to fix the aforementioned problem, it stopped working altogether.

P.S. Everything I mentioned is created dynamically through the code, if that matters.

Code:

```
#Declaring the variables
var temp_text_key = ""
var temp_text_value = ""

#Function to show up a dialogue window with LineEdits and Confirm button
func _on_add_new_property(dict: Dictionary):
    temporal_window_dialogue = WindowDialog.new()
    temporal_window_dialogue.rect_min_size = Vector2(410,90)
    temporal_window_dialogue.resizable = true
    temporal_window_dialogue.popup_exclusive = true
    temporal_window_dialogue.window_title = "Adding new property to %s" % get_dict_name_by_id(professions, dict["id"])
    
    var le_key = LineEdit.new()
    le_key.placeholder_text = "Name of the property"
    le_key.hint_tooltip = "Name of the property"
    le_key.connect("text_changed", self, "_on_add_new_prop_text_entered", ["key"])
    
    var le_value = LineEdit.new()
    le_value.expand_to_text_length = true
    le_value.placeholder_text = "Value of the property"
    le_value.set("custom_constants/minimum_spaces", 36)
    le_value.hint_tooltip = "Value of the property"
    le_value.connect("text_changed", self, "_on_add_new_prop_text_entered", ["value"])
    
    var lab = Label.new()
    lab.text = "Should the Value become a Dictionary?"
    
    var check_bt = CheckBox.new()
    
    var vbox = VBoxContainer.new()
    
    var grid_container = GridContainer.new()
    grid_container.columns = 2
    
    var accept_bt = Button.new()
    accept_bt.text = "Confirm"
    
    temporal_window_dialogue.add_child(vbox)
    vbox.add_child(grid_container)
    
    grid_container.add_child(le_key)
    grid_container.add_child(le_value)
    grid_container.add_child(lab)
    grid_container.add_child(check_bt)
    vbox.add_child(accept_bt)
    
    grid_container.set("custom_constants/vseparation", 5)
    grid_container.set("custom_constants/hseparation", 5)
    
    check_bt.connect("pressed", self, "_on_check_dict_pressed")
    
    popup_window.add_child(temporal_window_dialogue)
    temporal_window_dialogue.connect("popup_hide", self, "_on_close_specific_codegenerated_popup", [temporal_window_dialogue])
    
    temporal_window_dialogue.popup_centered()
    
    accept_bt.connect("pressed", self, "_on_add_new_property_confirmation", [dict, temp_text_key, temp_text_value])

#Function to create a new key/value pair in a dictionary
func _on_add_new_property_confirmation(dict: Dictionary, prop_name: String, prop_value: String):
    if prop_name == "" or prop_value == "":
        send_message_to_console("Neither of the two can be empty", 3)
        return
    if add_dictionary_flag:
        dict[prop_name] = {
            prop_value: {
                "id": get_free_local_id_for_dict(dict)
            }
        }
    elif !add_dictionary_flag:
        if keywords_for_dictionaries.has(prop_name):
            send_message_to_console("Only Dictionary items can become %s" % prop_name)
        dict[prop_name] = prop_value
    
    temp_text_key = ""
    temp_text_value = ""

#Optional function to write the text from LineEdits to the variables
func _on_add_new_prop_text_entered(new_text, key_or_value):
    if key_or_value == "key":
        temp_text_key = new_text
    elif key_or_value == "value":
        temp_text_value = new_text
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned using 'LineEdit.text', but have you tried the following?

var text = LineEdit.get_text()

If this doesn't help, please update your original post to include code examples.

Comment: that did not work either, unfortunately. I updated the post with the code example